# Do an extract() to a non associative array

Tags: php, arrays, extract

I have a non associative array and I want to extract values from it to 4 variables. Like we do with extract() function with associative arrays :

```
$AT = array("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4");
extract($AT);
```

How can I get the four variables now ? :(
Thanks ! ;)

Comment: And what variables with which value would you expect ?

Comment: Why would you want that? What names do you want to give to your variables? and what values? Do you expect like $T1 = "T1", etc?

Comment: you don't have any names for extract to produce variables from. you just have 4 values... if you expect php to do something like `$var = 'T1'`, then you have provide the name to use for `var`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, because [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) works on an associative array, not an enumerated array, unless you apply a prefix:

```
$AT = array("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4");
extract($AT, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'MyT');
```

Then you have variables `$MyT_0`, `$MyT_1`, `$MyT_2`, etc

Comment: Thanks so much :D
But to call variables I used $MyT_0